# Qt display double number without exponential format

Tags: c++, qt

Let's say that I have a double number: 1679616. When I try to set text to label, the number is shown as `1.67962e+06`. Is there a way so that the number can be shown as it is without exponential format?

If I use: `QString::number(result, 'f', 2)` to cast the number to string, everything is OK, but what if the number has more than two digits after that point? I know that I can set it to be 10 for example, but you know that this is not the right thing that I want to do. I want if the number is **82348.12323** to be shown **as it is**. If it is 234.2, I want just one number after the point.

Answer (score 4):

The following examples work pretty well for me:

```
double a1 = 82348.12323;
double a2 = 234.2;

QString s1 = QString::number(a1, 'g', 10);
QString s2 = QString::number(a2, 'g', 10);

qDebug() << "s1:" << s1;
qDebug() << "s2:" << s2;
```

Output:

```
s1: "82348.12323" 
s2: "234.2"
```

More information on the format argument can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlocale.html#toString-8).

Comment: setting a1 = 0.00001 will output as "1e-05" using this code.
consider using QString::number(a1, 'f', 10) instead

Comment: Not sure if this is what the OP was asking or not, but it was what I was after, so I'll leave it as a comment: `QString::number(std::numeric_limits<qreal>::min(), 'f', QLocale::FloatingPointShortest)` gives me what I was after - the _entire_ number.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using int64. I solved it by using a conversion to std::string thusly:

```
std::string tsSS2 = std::to_string(tStamp);
```

which converted an int64 (tStamp) to a std::string and then when I issued:

```
qDebug << tsSS2;
```

It printed the number without scientific notation (SN). Curiously it printed it with a decimal point and trailing zeros. Still, no SN.

Sean